# How to restore a Dell Inspiron 2100 back to factory settings?

Tags: windows-7, netbook, dell-latitude

My computer won't boot into Windows 7 anymore.

It started off with Vista, was upgraded to 7 (both by legal means)

I wanted to install ubuntu or kubuntu, so I got wubi and boot-loaded it via usb flash drive.

After that, windows 7 wouldn't start.  It would get as far as the green-metered progress bar on the bottom for about 10 seconds, but then would go right back to the bios screen after that.

I have Hiren's BootCD 10.1, windows xp cd, and (obviously) an external usb cd drive.

Anyone know what tool(s) to use to restore this computer so that I can boot windows xp cd and setup/install it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have got a recovery CD/DVD with the computer you should use that.

If you haven't got one of these, things are in a far worse state. If you want to install XP, insert the CD and set it as the boot device in the BIOS (or at a 'Boot media' screen). Just be sure not to overwrite your Windows 7 partition.

You could always try to request a recovery CD from Dell support if you have lost the one (if you got one) that came with your computer.

Comment: i think i need to fix the boot.ini, bios settings, and/or master boot record.  any idea?

Comment: Boot.ini is pure OS level, you can't modify this without having the OS installed. Plus, Windows 7 doesn't uses another bootloader than XP. There is obviously nothing wrong with the MBR since it starts booting. The BIOS settings would only need to be modified if you plan on installing XP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Windows 7 DVD and use the repair wizard to see if windows can fix it for you. If you don't have a Windows 7 DVD then download the Windwows 7 Repair Disk from the links end of [this page.](http://neosmart.net/blog/2009/windows-7-system-repair-discs/)

Give it a shot and let us know what happens.

Comment: thanks for the link - I'll def give it a shot, but I really want xp.  windows 7 is no fun